# FullCalendar displaying without css or any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

So I'm trying to get full calendar installed on my website, and after a few issues, I managed to get to a point where I have no errors but the calendar itself isn't displaying correctly (like it doesn't have css).

I checked, and as far as I can tell, all of the files that need to be referenced are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html><head>    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- FullCalender files references -->
<script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
<script src='src/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='src/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src="src/gcal.js"></script>

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="components/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link src="src/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link src="src/fullcalendar.print.css"  rel="stylesheet">ipt>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'KEY',
                events: {
                    googleCalendarId: 'ID@group.calendar.google.com'
                }
            });
        });
    </script><title>Western PA ARML</title></head>    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Western PA ARML</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> -->
            <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="join.html">Join the Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="coaches.html">People</a></li>  
            <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="pictures.html">Photos</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  <body>
      <div id="content"><div class="section">
    <h1>Calendar</h1>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>  </div> <!--Content-->
    <div class="footer">
    &#9400; 2017 Western Pennsylvania ARML Team
  </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug 
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks - [image: How the Calendar looks]
[image]

Comment: don't use fullCalendar.io as a CDN (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661362/fullcalendar-doesnt-display-on-live-site/48662376#48662376). Use the CDNJS for everything as recommended here: https://fullcalendar.io/download/. And your CSS and JS versions don't match. Use the same fullCalendar version for all the files. Did you really seriously expect v2.1 of the calendar code to seamlessly work with v3.8.2 of the CSS? Stick to the latest version for everything and also make sure you use compatible versions of jQuery and momentJS too, as documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/support/

Comment: Oh, and `<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="src/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>` also seems to be redundant, since you already included jQuery just above. This seems to be a shim anyway to check whether jQuery has already been loaded somewhere else earlier in the page before deciding to load it again. This shouldn't be necessary in any situation anyhow - you're designing the page, you know whether you've included jQuery or not, because you wrote the code. And also this is included after fullCalendar, so if this was the first load of jQuery, fullCalendar would fail.

Comment: There seems to be nothing on your page which would require the inclusion of jQuery-UI, and there's no particular reason to put the bootstrap JS file at the bottom, all your JS files should be included together, if at all possible - it's better for readability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: And you have HTML which is outside both the head and body tags. This is not valid. Anything you want to display should be inside `<body>`. Many browsers might be tolerant of this but it's messy and technically invalid HTML, so you can't _expect_ it to work properly.

Comment: Listen, I appreciate the help I really do, but attacking me like with "It feels like you didn't really look closely at the documentation, or at your own code, or think through what you were doing before throwing a half-baked page together." won't help anyone. I'm new to this, so I apologize for missing things, but I have given it everything which is why I'm here.

I added the gcal, and now I get this error - gcal.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventSource' of undefined

Comment: I switched everything to the same version and moved everything away from CDN. No change :(

Comment: well I take your point but equally there are some quite basic things here. Even as a beginner, surely you didn't imagine that two different versions would just work together automatically? Otherwise what's the point of different versions? I just meant you should check your work more carefully and read the documentation available - you missed adding a necessary file as well, which is clearly described on the website.

Comment: So when you say you "moved everything away from CDN" - you mean you're hosting it all within your site? Are you sure you have the correct version of all the files? If you do, then the code should work no problem.

Comment: e.g. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/193/ . It doesn't fully work because the API credentials and calendar ID are invalid, but you can test by replacing them with your own to see what happens. All the 3.8.2 files from the CDN are loaded, in the correct order (see the "Resources" section in the sidebar, plus jQuery is loaded directly by JSFiddle). So in your own solution you need to make sure you have included all the correct files in the correct order, and that your Google info is right. That's all there is to it. If you aren't using the CDN, you just have to check a little more carefully.

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded everything and now have it locally hosted. Made sure it's all the same version (3.8.2) as well as download moments.js locally but I'm still getting that error from before about the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventSource' of undefined`. That error is coming for the gcal.min.js is seems. I've also noticed that I don't have the jquery-ui. Where would I get that?

And seriously, thank you for the help and sorry for my stupidity

Comment: No problem, I didn't intend to come across as rude, so I apologise for that too. You don't need jQuery-UI for this. If you do decide you want it for any reason, it's hosted on the same CDN, or you can download it from http://jqueryui.com/ . It has some useful features but nothing directly relevant to this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see your current code or know whether you've really got everything correct. If you still have an error, it seems unlikely. Did you try my suggestion using the JSFiddle link I gave you, putting your Google credentials in there to see if you can see the calendar? If that works, it rules out your google info as the source of the problem.

Comment: You can also edit the question to show your current code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, my question has been updated to show what I have right now. Thank you again. The Fiddle works

Comment: Playing a simple game of spot the difference between the Fiddle and your version, you simply need to load gcal.js _after_ fullCalendar.min.js. Which makes sense because it's an extension of fullCalendar's functionality. It depends on fullCalendar functionality which doesn't exist if it gets loaded before fullCalendar.

Comment: I see! I don't know where you see the load order in jsfiddle but thank you. So now it loads!!!! but the css is messed up :( Why am I having so many problems with this? I updated the question with the new image

Comment: I found the list in the fiddle and copied it but it's still not showing the css :(

Comment: 1) I realised your `link` tags are specified incorrectly. You need to put the URL in a "href" attribute, not a "src" (that's used for `script` tags). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link  2) you're loading the "print" CSS and the regular CSS both into the code, but the "print" style will override the regular style (because it's loaded later). You need to put a media query in the "print" one to ensure it only gets used when the user tries to print the page. e.g. `<link href="src/fullcalendar.print.css"  rel="stylesheet" media="print">`

Comment: OMG THAT'S SO STUPID OF ME! I know better, I even have the bootstrap one done correctly. I'm so sorry for wasting your time. It works now, I'm so grateful for your help :D

How do I mark that as the answer?

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. Again all of this is really about checking the fine detail. A lot of programming comes down to making sure every little bit is "just so" :-)

Comment: I can write it all into an answer which you can tick, hang on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things which are issues with your code (starting from the original edit up to the current version):

1) You need to make sure your CSS and JS files are all based on the same version of fullCalendar, and also that your jQuery and momentJS files are compatible versions, and loaded in the correct order (see https://fullcalendar.io/support/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ respectively).

2) Don't use fullCalendar.io as a CDN. Either use the recommended CDNJS site (as per https://fullcalendar.io/download/) or download and host the files yourself.

3) `<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="src/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>` seems to be redundant, since you already included jQuery just above.

4) `gcal.js` needs to be loaded *after* `fullCalendar.js`, because it depends on it in order to work properly.

5) I realised your `<link>` tags are specified incorrectly. You need to put the URL in a "href" attribute, not a "src" (that's used for script tags). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link fpr the spec.

6) You're loading the "print" CSS and the regular CSS both into the code, but the "print" style will override the regular style (because it's loaded later). You need to put a media query in the "print" one to ensure it only gets used when the user tries to print the page. e.g.

```
<link href="src/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

---

Additional side comments:

1) You don't need jQuery-UI for this to work, and nothing else on your page seems to make use of it, so you can remove it.

2) You have HTML which is outside both the `<head>` and `<body>` tags. This is not valid. Anything you want to display should be inside `<body>`. Many browsers might be tolerant of this problem but it's messy and technically invalid HTML, so you can't *expect* it to always work properly.

Answer (score -1):

You're placing your css in the wrong place.

```
<link href="components/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.2/fullcalendar.print.css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

Placing the code like this will cause external css resources to override your custom css.

Instead place it like this:

```
<link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.2/fullcalendar.print.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<link href="components/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, aren't my links the css?

Comment: Ah, I see! I gave it a shot, but it's still looking the same way :(